# Strange sum in matrix theory

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I was doing some Matrix theory when a strange sum appered.

Exercise:
Suppose that $N$ is a nilpotent matrix of index $n$. Show that the equation 
$$X^2 = I + N$$ has a solution 
$$ X = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} {\frac{1}{2}\choose{k}} N^k.$$

There was a hint to this exercise:

Because $(1+x)^{\alpha} = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} {\alpha\choose{k}} x^k$
for $|x|<1$ the function $f(x)=(1+x)^{1/2}$ is defined on $A$ if the eigenvalues of $A$ satisfy $|\lambda_i| < 1 $ besides that $f(A)^2 = I + A$. This definitly works for $A=N$

The strange sum is this one $(1+x)^{\alpha} = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} {\alpha\choose{k}} x^k$ I have never seen this one before. It looks familiar to binomial expansion. I can not understand where this sume comes from? 
Usually it is $(1+x)^{n} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} {n\choose{k}} x^k$

Where does this sum come from? What happends when $k>\alpha$?

Keep in mind that I have not studied integration theory.

Comment: See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Binomial_coefficient_with_n_.3D_.C2.BD) article in wikipedia.

Comment: Note also that $N^k=0$ for $k\ge n$, so the series is actually a *finite* sum of the first $n$ terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to think about this sum. The easiest (I think) is to say that we are simply using the Taylor series for the function $\sqrt{1 + x}$ centered at $x = 0$.

In general, $\binom{\alpha}k$ is the coefficient of $x^k$ in the power-series expansion of $(1+x)^\alpha$. For an actual formula, see [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Generalization_and_connection_to_the_binomial_series).